# Icon does not disappear from "all applications" after uninstalling DeadBeef

Tags: icons, uninstall, gnome-shell

I uninstalled DeadBeef after testing it and the icon did not disappear. Some screenshots of the problem:

**Icon in "all applications":**
[image: Icon on "all aplications"]

**Uninstalled app from store:**
[image: Uninstalled app from store]

I have already rebooted, I used the remove and purge commands in the terminal

Comment: If you run `which deadbeef` (assuming the command to start it is deadbeef) do you still it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `~/.local/share/applications/` folder for a `.desktop` launcher that may still exist for this application and was not potentially removed. If there is, deleting that particular `.desktop` file should solve the problem.

Checking `/usr/share/applications/` for this as well may also be useful, but tinkering in your root folder can be dangerous, proceed with caution!